# Calculate the $r$-derivative of the function $f$

Tags: complex-analysis, derivatives

Let $f$ be an analytic function defined by

$$f(s)=g(s)∑_{n=1}^{∞}a_{n}/n^{s}$$

where $∑_{n=1}^{∞}a_{n}/n^{s}$ is an absolute convergent series for $Re(s)>1$.

I have the **following question**:

Calculate the $r$- th derivative of the function $f$ for $Re(s)>1$, i.e., f^{(r)}(s).  The expression of the $g$ is not important in this case.

Comment: What does the "$r$-derivative" mean?

Comment: @PeterTamaroff: $f^{(r)}(s)$ with respect to $s$.

Comment: You can call the the $r$-**th** derivative.

Comment: @PeterTamaroff: Ok I add this comment.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will have to use Leibniz's rule that says that $$(f\cdot g)^{(r)}=\sum_{k=0}^r\binom{r}{k}f^{(k)}g^{(r-k)}$$

where $f^{(0)}=f$ and $g^{(0)}=g$, plus the fact that you can differentiate $f$ term-wise. You will have to use $$\left(\frac{d}{ds}\right)^{r}n^{-s}=(-1)^rn^{-s}\log^r n$$

too.